# Chart which shows the number of occurrences for each date

Tags: sql, charts, powerbi, dax

I have a database that has the column start_date.
That column contains the dates when the accounts were created.
Since there are multiple accounts were created each day, there are many identical entries for the same date (see image below)

[start_date column sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K411b.png)

I need to create the chart that represents how many accounts started each day.
I tried to measure the number of occurrences but I'm getting results that has nothing to do with it, such as 365, which is a number of days per year.

Here is what I tried:

Measure =
COUNTROWS (
FILTER (
VALUES ( Query1[start_date] ),
CALCULATE ( COUNT ( Query1[start_date] ))
)
)

And it returns 30 which is equal to the timeframe that I set in filters (entries from Jul 18 to Aug 18).

So, I can't figure out how to calculate the number of rows with the same date and represent it like this:

[The result that I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G71WQ.png)

Please, bear with me, and sorry for the noob question, my boss wants me to start using PowerBi, this is my very first task and I can't figure out how to handle it.

Comment: I suggest doing some basic power bi tutorials to get you up and running.

Comment: @David I'm on it. I just have to finish it today. My boss told me "You are programmer, so it won't take much time for you to figure it out" while I've never used Power BI. 
I'm a programmer, so I can figure out how to fix fridges in a few minutes.

Comment: You should tell your boss he doesn't know what he's talking about. Power Bi is not excel and it takes some time to become competent.

Comment: @David Power BI is the father, and Excel is his son. When the son can't take care of big datasets, he consults to his father to get the job done!

Comment: Add your measure and result, so you can get some valuable comments. And it will be easer to understanding what you gonna achieve.

Comment: @Mik Just added. I hope it makes my goal more clear

Comment: what did you get with this `COUNT ( Query1[start_date] )` ? I'll explain your measure 3-4 hours later as I have to go now.

Comment: @Mik I'm getting 8034 which is the total number of rows

Comment: @RegBox You can obtain the related code, but It is much more important to learn why It is written so. If your aim is just to make your boss happy, then It is a wrong strategy. you don't know some basic concepts. It will be difficult to understand it.

Comment: Definitely. I will understand why it's written so, when I'll see it. 
That's how we all learned the coding - by looking at examples.

Comment: I made a small change. I replaced sum with count.

Comment: Thank you, @OzanSen. 
I just tried it, and it shows exactly the same result (total number of rows) as COUNT ( Query1[start_date] )

Comment: You did slice& dice. As in your image, did you put date column in x_axis, and measure on Y_axis ?

Comment: Yes, and it looks like this https://i.imgur.com/n02g1Qk.png

Comment: (I Updated it) Your_Measure =
VAR SummaryTbl =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        VALUES ( Query1[start_date] ),
        "TotalCount", CALCULATE ( COUNT ( Query1[start_date] ) )
    )
VAR Result =
    SUMX ( SummaryTbl, [TotalCount] )
RETURN
    Result

Comment: @OzanSen Thanks! 
So, after running your code it added column VALUES that looks like this https://i.imgur.com/dZWuzhQ.png
Values must contain 31 rows, since there are 31 unique dates ranging from Jul 18 to Aug 18, but for some reason it added VALUE to each row in the database. Also, it was added in text format, so the value is incorrect as you can see.

Comment: Please check your data type is date or date time, not text/string

Comment: Also, please check the answer of @Peter. He is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any measure for this. Take a Clustered column chart and put start_date both on X-axis and Y-axis. By default Power BI will set the aggregation on the Y-axis to Count of start_date and you'll get exactly the picture that you're looking for.

[image]